# Render partial by AJAX

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

**Description**

I have the following working code.

- View with list of links:

  ```
    <%= div_for feed do %>
      <%= link_to feed.name, { :controller => 'Feeds', :action => "get_posts", :id => feed.id }, 
    :remote => true %>  
    <% end %>
  ```
- Controller which works when user clicks the link:

  ```
    def get_posts
      @result = Feed.find(params[:id]).generate_html_table    

      respond_to do | format |  
        format.js {render :layout => false}  
      end
    end
  ```
- Method which generates HTML:

  ```
    def generate_html_table
        r = "<table>"

        self.posts.order("published desc").each { |p|                   
            link = '<a href=' + p.link + '>' + p.title + '</a>'
            date = '  ' + p.published.to_s

            r += '<tr><td>' + link + '</td><td>' + date + '</td></tr>'
        }    

        r + '</table>'
    end
  ```
- And get_posts.js.erb:

  ```
    $( "#in" ).html("<%= raw @result %>");
  ```

Users clicks the link, generate_html_table generates HTML code which inserted into #id div.

**Question**

I want to change generate_html_table with partials. How can I get it?

**How did I try it**

- I have created file views/feeds/_posts.html.erb with:

  ```
    some static text
  ```
- I have edit my get_posts.js.erb as:

  ```
    $( "#in" ).html("<%= escape_javascript(render :partial => 'posts' )%>");
  ```

But even now, with static text it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you have view code in the controller, you should get rid of the `generate_html_table` method and leave that to the `get_posts.js.erb`, when you are putting code that belongs to a view so clearly you know you are going offtrack.

The `get_posts.js.erb` you have in the second part of the question seems right, I don't see a `#in` in your previous view code where that code would be inserted, have you checked calling the ajax URL directly to discard a problem in the ajax part? (like not having loaded the `jquery-ujs` or whatever unobtrusive javascript platform you are using). I also don't see any code that is handling the `remote`, so the javascript that is returning from the call is probably not being used.

My recommendation would be:

- get rid of `generate_html_table`
- leave the gathering of the posts you want to gather (`self.posts.order("published desc")`) in the controller, that does belong in the controller
- add code to the asset of your page to handle the `ajax:success` callback of your button to insert the html in `#in`
- don't return javascript in your ajax call, rather return the HTML that you need to insert, let the client handle the javascript part

Answer (score 0):

You may try using a bit more the js templates

The problem over here is that you are mixing a lot of responsabilities, try to divide them a little bit more.

### Example:

**Controller:**

You can move the `order` into a scope in the model.

```
def get_posts
  @posts = Feed.find(params[:id]).order("published desc")

  respond_to do | format |  
    format.js 
  end
end
```

**Model:**

- The model has no need to know how to render out a list of posts.
- Extract the `generate_html_table` method.

**View:**

Implement the old `generate_html_table` in the view template

```
<div id="in">
  <table>
  <% @posts.each do |p|  %>
    <tr> 
      <td> <%= j (link_to p.title, p.link) %> </td>
      <td><%= j p.published.to_s %> </td>
    </tr>
  <% end %>                
  </table>
</div>
```

NOTE: Haven't test this code, but something like this should work.